# Is there a way I can do a ng-repeat that covers more than one array with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I have the following that loops through xa and prints the qs.a.text values:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="a in xa">
   <div data-ng-bind-html="a.text"></div>
</div>

<div data-ng-repeat="b in xb">
   <div data-ng-bind-html="b.text"></div>
</div>
```

Is there a way that I could combine these something like this:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="a in xa and xb">
   <div data-ng-bind-html="a.text"></div>
   <div data-ng-bind-html="b.text"></div>
</div>
```

Note that xa and xb are arrays that always contain exactly the same number of elements.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure, you can use javascript's `concat()` to concatenate the arrays and then use the results for your repeat.

As such:

```
<div data-ng-repeat="item in combined = xa.concat(xb)">
   <div data-ng-bind-html="item.text"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sweet! great solution!

Comment: @Ognjen I notice that if I have an ng-repeat on an array and that array changes, the view will automatically changes. Is this what you are referring to? So if either on of those arrays were to change the view would not be updated? That is pretty disappointing. Luckily this solution works for my current need. But it would be cool to see a solution that *does* change the view when one of the arrays change. I personally need them to be combined this way rather than the solutions below because then I can `orderBy`.

Answer (score 3):

you can use $index. it represents the current index of the ng-repeat

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/998/)**

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrA" class="container">
    <div>{{arrA[$index].text}}</div>
    <div>{{arrB[$index].text}}</div>
</div>
```

Though you may want to combine your arrays in to one with something like undescorejs instead of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div data-ng-repeat="a in xa">
   <div data-ng-bind-html="a.text"></div>
   <div data-ng-bind-html="xb[$index].text"></div>
</div>
```