# ng-repeat on one of two arrays based on condition

Tags: angularjs

Say I have

```
<div ng-if="groupA.length > 0" ng-repeat="element in groupA"> .... </div>
<div ng-if="groupA.length == 0" ng-repeat="element in groupB"> .... </div>
```

Both divs are exactly the same HTML except for the if conditions and the fact that they repeat on two different groups. Am I able to join them together in one div element? I.e. `<div ng-repeat="element in (groupA || groupB)"> ... </div>`

I know I can check in the controller to and have a condition there like `groupC = groupA.length > 0 ? groupA : groupB` and have in the html `<div ng-repeat="element in groupC> ... </div>` but I was wondering if there's a way to do it on HTML directly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way I can do a ng-repeat that covers more than one array with AngularJS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20021777/is-there-a-way-i-can-do-a-ng-repeat-that-covers-more-than-one-array-with-angular)

Comment: `<div ng-repeat="element in ($ctrl.groupA.length > 0 ?  $ctrl.groupA : $ctrl.groupB)"> {{element}} </div>` should work - https://plnkr.co/edit/2oHUvSHB6Vjsc1vNhc5S?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should work with ternary operators. Demo: https://plnkr.co/edit/yqrUb2UNAasFs4EKaf0b

```
<div ng-repeat="element in (groupA.length > 0 ? groupA : groupB)"> .... </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just add a condition inside the ng-repeat like as

```
<div ng-repeat="element in (groupA.length > 0 ? groupA : groupB)"> </div>
```

Hope this will help you